# Why do these 3 queries not returning the correct records

Tags: mysql, sql, union, union-all

I have this SQL query that returns 4 columns and 45 rows.

```
Select ComplaintID, ProblemStreet, ProblemCrossStreet,ProblemSubdivision
 From Complaints 
 where ProblemCrossStreet Like '%PARK MANOR%' OR ProblemStreet Like '%PARK 
MANOR%' Or ProblemSubdivision Like '%PARK MANOR%'
```

This Query returns 4 columns and 31 rows:

```
DECLARE @a as varchar(Max) = 'PARK MANOR'
Select ComplaintID, ProblemStreet, ProblemCrossStreet,ProblemSubdivision
From Complaints 
 where ProblemCrossStreet Like @a OR ProblemStreet Like @a Or 
ProblemSubdivision Like @a
```

And This Query is what I need to return it should be 2 columns and 45 rows

```
DECLARE @a as varchar(Max) = 'PARK MANOR'
Select  ComplaintID,ProblemCrossStreet From Complaints Where 
ProblemCrossStreet like @a
Union ALL
Select ComplaintID,ProblemStreet from Complaints Where ProblemStreet Like @a
Union ALL
Select ComplaintID, ProblemSubdivision From Complaints where 
ProblemSubdivision like @a
```

How ever the last query only returns 34 rows?  Why does these 3 queries that seem to be the same not return the same values and most of all how can I get my third query to return those 2 columns and 45 rows?

Comment: This query will be used as a stored procedure that would get a varchar similar to what I set in the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your variable like, with %.

```
DECLARE @a as varchar(Max) = '%PARK MANOR%'
```

Or update your queries to add %

```
where ProblemCrossStreet Like CONCAT('%', @a, '%') OR ProblemStreet Like CONCAT('%', @a, '%') Or 
ProblemSubdivision Like CONCAT('%', @a, '%')
```

Comment: I plan to use this in a stored procedure so how could I set that '%PARK MANOR%' value?

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
ProblemCrossStreet Like 'PARK MANOR'
```

and

```
ProblemCrossStreet Like '%PARK MANOR%'
```

do different things.  The first looks for an exact(ish) match.  The second looks for the pattern anywhere in the name.

As for the third query, it is using `union all`.  So, if a single row matches two conditions then then form returns two rows.

It is not clear which you really want.  If you want wildcard matching, then include wildcards in the `like` pattern.  If you want a separate row for each match, then use `union all`.

EDIT:

You appear to want:

```
declare @a as varchar(Max) = 'PARK MANOR';

Select  ComplaintID, ProblemCrossStreet
From Complaints
Where ProblemCrossStreet like concat('%', @a, '%')
Union ALL
Select ComplaintID, ProblemStreet
from Complaints
Where ProblemStreet Like concat('%', @a, '%')
Union ALL
Select ComplaintID, ProblemSubdivision
From Complaints
where ProblemSubdivision like concat('%', @a, '%');
```

Comment: I am trying to get all 45 matches from the 1st query reduced down to 2 columns using a stored procedure that would be passed the Name.  That was why I tried the union all

Comment: @Perry . . . I find it unusual that you unaccepted this answer.  This didn't do what you want?